Removing extra characters from code environment in beamer
I tried to write some programming code in beamer and some extra characters appear on each line before the code. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.
Here's my MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble} %to remove indentation
\lstset{ %
    language=C,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    autogobble=true, % Removes indentation based on first line
}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]{First program}
        \begin{lstlisting}
            int main(){
                printf("hello");
                return 0;
            }
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}

Here's the output:

Also, the characters appear in the normal font and not the monospace font.
What's wrong with my code?
Edit #1:
The output without the gobble package:

Edit #2: I'm using TeXStudio editor and MiKTex distribution. Here's the link to the log.

@cfr It doesn't look like it. I have edited my question above to include the output without the gobble package.

@cfr I tried doing that, but the result is the same. In fact I typed the code by hand to avoid any character conversion errors, but nope. It looks like it has something to do with the indentation, those extra characters seems to fill the indentation space. Also, the font is not monospaced, not sure why this is the case. I tried the same in article class, but same story.

I also can't reproduce the problem. Tested by last version of MiKTeX.

@cfr I've updated my question.

^^I is the same as a <Tab> character. I'd guess you have tab-based indentation in your file and something in your preamble you don't show (because even with tabs for spaces I can't reproduce your behaviour).

@Skillmon you're right, the tab was the issue, now it looks right. I can't thank you enough. But it is still not in monospace font. Any idea why that happens?

That's just the default setting of listings, use basestyle=\ttfamily in your \lstset.

@Skillmon Thanks a lot. I believe it's basicstyle=\ttfamily. Thanks again.

Well, was typing the key from memory :) The gist is the same.

if you did actually copy back the code from here and reproduced the issue from precisely that code, then (1) your editor is converting spaces to tabs and (2) something else is going on, since @Skillmon says even tabs don't reproduce the issue.

@bahaksekldhi I wouldn't use xelatex with beamer. If you need an unicode engine, I would suggest using lualatex instead. Xelatex can cause some strange problems in beamer, like missing text on note pages and differences in uncovering text.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks for the tip. I did once use Lualatex but there was some inconvenience I don't remember exactly what it is right now, so I switched back to xelatex.

@cfr Yes, the code above is "tabbed", which was the culprit.

In TeX the notation ^^<char> means use the character at ASCII-code of <char>-64 (for <char> having an ASCII-code >= 64 that is). For ^^I you end at ASCII-code 73-64=9 which is Tab. So my guess (because one can't reproduce this from your MWE) is that you're using tabs for indentation in your source file and something in your preamble messes with them in a way that listings show their ^^I representation instead of interpreting them the usual way (normally listings turns them into whitespace). So if you change your indentation to use spaces you should be fine (or you search for whatever creates your problem with tabs).
The second part of your question about the font being the text font: That's just listings default setting. If you want to change that simply set basicstyle=\ttfamily to get your document's monospace font for your code.

I can reproduce the issue: been there, done that!

@egreg oh, I never use XeLaTeX personally so had no idea! Good to know. Anyway +1!

The mysterious ^^I in the output mean two things:

you're using TAB for indenting the code;
you're using XeLaTeX to process your beamer document.

I learned several years ago that TABs in TeX files are evil. But you can still use them with XeLaTeX if you so prefer. The problem is evident if you look at the autogenerated file created by the fragile option, with extension .vrb
\frametitle{First program}

^^I^^I\begin{lstlisting}
^^I^^I^^Iint main(){
^^I^^I^^I^^Iprintf("hello");
^^I^^I^^I^^Ireturn 0;
^^I^^I^^I}
^^I^^I\end{lstlisting}


For reasons that only Jonathan Kew knows, XeTeX writes out TAB using the ^^I notation. This can be avoided by calling xelatex with the -8bit option (how to do it depends on the front-end you're using). If I do it, the written file will become
\frametitle{First program}

        \begin{lstlisting}
            int main(){
                printf("hello");
                return 0;
            }
        \end{lstlisting}


(with TABs; if you copy-paste from here you'll get spaces, because the site's engine, like me, doesn't like TABs ).
And the output will be OK.
A couple of notes.
I'd not indent everything in the document environment: it just makes code difficult to read and the code is first level.
Second note: you see in the .vrb file that beamer transforms the trailing argument to \begin{frame} into \frametitle{...}. Do it yourself, it's clearer and more flexible.
Last: if you want monospaced characters, tell it to listings.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble} %to remove indentation
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=flexible,
    language=C,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    autogobble=true, % Removes indentation based on first line
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{First program}

        \begin{lstlisting}
                int main(){
                        printf("hello");
                        return 0;
                }
        \end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

(the code indentation is obtained with TABs in the original file).
Compiling with xelatex -8bit the output will be


Yes to both. I wasn't aware of this "bug" with the xelatex engine. I used tab only because the editor tabs-out automatically and I didn't want to press backspace for every line. I guess I'll just use lualatex to avoid all this. Thanks for the clear explanation.
